# Finding Hamiltonian path in an undirected sparse graph

Tags: algorithm, performance, graph, time-complexity, depth-first-search

I have an undirected graph that I know will always have a hamiltonian path

So I've implemented DFS with backtracking to find one solution and return it.
[image: dfs backtracking]

The problem is that it takes a lot of time to find a solution when I have a sparse graph.

For example:

I have 50 nodes with 1000 edges, it will take 100 ms to find a solution

I have 50 nodes with 100 edges, it will take 10000 ms to find a solution

I have 100 nodes with 3000 edges, it will take 100 ms to find a solution

I have 100 nodes with 200 edges, it will take several hours to find a solution

Is there any better way to find only one hamiltonian path for sparse graphs? It's already really fast in dense graphs since I'm looking for only one solutions among severals, but in sparse graphs, since there are way less solutions, DFS with backtracking doesn't seem like a good choice (I have to be really lucky to find the solution rapidly).

Thank you!

Comment: This problem is known to be NP-hard, so (barring P = NP) you're either going to have to spend a lot of time or settle for heuristics or randomized algorithms. Are you okay with either option?

Comment: In terms of exact solutions, the best you can really hope for here is to find efficient, high-quality *pruning rules*.  One that might be worth trying: At each node in the search tree, check whether the remaining nodes form a single connected component (either with DFS, or if you're clever, with a faster incremental algorithm).  If they don't, then there's no possible way to join them up with your path so far to form a cycle, so you can exit (prune) this search node.